# Executing a piece of code one after the other

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

As part of my application that I am creating, I am implement a run tracking feature. I have majority of the code in but I have a section of code that is almost executing too quickly, I need a response back from the newRun.php script before the next section of code executes, this is due to it returning an ID which I require to execute the next section of code.

```
    @IBAction func stopRun(_ sender: Any)
    {
       startButton.isHidden=false
       stopButton.isHidden=true
       saveRun()
    }
```

Above is the section of code where it runs saveRun. On this button click I want it to create a new record in a 'run_history' table. ONLY ONCE this has complete, I then want it to create new  record(s) with the run_id that the `newRun.php` script returns which will include all the longitude and latitude degrees of the run.

```
    private func saveRun()
    {
```

To be executed first.

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "../newRun.php")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "id=\(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.user_id)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)



    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
    {
        data, response, error in



        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id = responseString! as String
        print ("Run ID =\(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id))")
    }
    task.resume()
```

To be executed secondly.

```
    for location in self.locationList
    {
        var timestamp = location.timestamp
        var latitude:String = String(format:"%f", location.coordinate.latitude)
        var longitude:String = String(format:"%f", location.coordinate.longitude)

        print("Timestamp is \(timestamp)")
        print("latitude is \(latitude)")
        print("longitude is \(longitude)")
        let requestGps = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "../newRunGps.php")! as URL)
        requestGps.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postStringGps = "id=\(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id)&lng=\(longitude)&lat=\(latitude)&time=\(timestamp)"
        requestGps.httpBody = postStringGps.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let taskGps = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestGps as URLRequest)
        {
            dataGps, responseGps, errorGps in

            if errorGps != nil
            {
                print("error=\(String(describing: errorGps))")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(String(describing: responseGps))")

            let responseStringGps = NSString(data: dataGps!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print ("responseString =\(responseStringGps!))")
        }
        taskGps.resume()
    }

}
```

I have seen mentions of DispatchQueue's and DispatchGroup's but I am unsure how I would use these in my code if anyone could help me out with this?

Comment: from your code it seems that you don't run `saveRun`.. make sure you format the code properly and that the brackets are properly matched

Comment: provide the code as is and indicate which part happens too soon

Comment: The bit that happens too soon is from 'for location in self.locationList'

Comment: look at your question and code that you provided. you declare a `saveRun` method. you do NOT call it. then you run `for` loop. include the whole relevenant code, with the part where you call `saveRun` and then the rest

Comment: I call saveRun elsewhere in my code, all I want to know is how to execute from the for loop AFTER the first let request.

Comment: now you edited it even worse.. put there the `saveRun` code separately, then the code that you want to run after it, and update the question text to explain it properly

Comment: Do you understand that edit?

Comment: is `for location in self.locationList` a part of the `saveRun` implementation? because at first version of the question it seemed that it is not (i assumed it is called from somewhere else)

Comment: Yes, `for` loop IS part of `saveRun` implementation

Comment: see my answer for probably the easiest and most straightforward solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4), execute: {
                    for vc in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? []) {
                        if vc is DashboardViewController {
                            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
                            break
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use "defer"

```
{
    defer {

        //code run after below defer
    }
    defer{
        // code run first
    }

}
```

But remember one thing this defer will execute just before end of the scope

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that `MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id` is set in a callback of an asynchronous method, which means `DispatchQueue` nor `defer` will help you here.

The easiest way to deal with it is to put the `for` loop inside of the callback itself. Thus it will be always ensured that it will be executed only **after** the call was executed:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "../newRun.php")! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "id=\(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.user_id)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
{
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil
    {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id = responseString! as String
    print ("Run ID =\(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id))")

    // here run the for loop
    for location in self.locationList {
         // TODO: rest of the for loop code
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Just make sure that if you do anything with the UI (setting text to UILabel, etc.), enqueue that code on main thread (in your case it seems you just send the data to the server, so you don't need to deal with that).